# hide show details with jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a table that each **row** have a detail to show.

so, when user mouseover's, detail will apear.

i made this:

**html:**

```
   <tr>    
      <td class="tdMsg">
            <span class='showDetail'/>Show</span>
            <div style='display: none;' class="divDetail">
                 // hidden div with some detail's
            </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

**js:**

```
$(".showDetail").live("mouseover", function(){
    $(".divDetail").hide();
    $(this).next().stop(true,true).fadeIn('fast');
});

$(".showDetail").live("mouseout", function(){
    $(".divDetail").hide();
});
```

but i wanna know if are any better way to do this instead puting a div in each row that need a detail, maybe using append or any other.

ps.: this was a fast example to explain what i'm trying to do, ignore the mouseover/mouseout separated with live.

thanks!

Comment: I'd say this would be the best way to do something like this; But if anyone else has a better option, I'd like to see that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have the show anchor and the details in two separate td's? and show/hide the details td content (innerHTML). That way you are limiting the divs.

In the future you might consider the <details> tag for HTML5, it is meant for toggle-able content. But right now only Chrome really does anything with it (hides it automatically).

Comment: I used this one: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-details to make it work for more browsers

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would add would be to use JQuery to do the initial hiding rather than inline CSS.

instead of:

```
<div style='display: none;' class="divDetail">
             // hidden div with some detail's
        </div>
```

do

```
$('.divDetail').hide();
```